# Kohana tags alternatives

Tags: support, tags

Because I do not have enough rights to report it to *SO*, so I'm doing it here.

The following tags should be combined:

- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/kohana
- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/kohana-3
- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/kohana-3.3
- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/kohana-orm

Kohana is a framework that has lost much popularity and is basically only used in legacy projects. Average question rate is 1/month.

v3.3.0 was released  [23 Oct 2012](https://github.com/kohana/core/tree/v3.3.0) (6 years ago)

The latest [version 3.3.6 was released on 25](https://kohanaframework.org/#history). July 2016.

Latest 3.2 releases was [5 years ago](https://github.com/kohana/core/tree/v3.2.3.1)

`kohana-orm` module now is integrated in `kohana`

Please also consider adding aliases: `koseven`. This is ***Successor of the Kohana Framework - fully compatible with PHP7+***

//EDIT

- `kohana` is framework name
- `kohana-3` - At the time of creation it made sense, because ko3 was basically a new framework (completely different file structure than in kohana-2)
- `kohana-3.3` - it's the most popular version, the lastest official version.

At the moment, these are synonyms.

- `kohana-orm` - Is part of `kohana`
- `koseven` it can be named: new name `kohana` or branch kohana 3.3 for PHP7, eg [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51609723/kohana-3-3-routing-with-subfolders-working-on-windows-but-failed-on-linux) It starts form [3.3.6](https://github.com/koseven/koseven/tags). It's old code, new team

//edit

An acceptable solution is also to block the addition of these tags to new questions, leaving the same `kohana`.

Comment: Thanks to dyslexia, I thought it was about a "Hidden Leaf Village"..

Answer (score 4):

We usually don't change tags just because a framework lost popularity. When the tags had relevance at the time when they were used, then what's the point in removing them now?

A successor should should also never be a synonym for the old library (unless the project was simply renamed). If it is a fork that was further developed, then creating a new tag might be a good idea, but at the time of writing there are no recent questions on SO. If a question about kohana shows up, then the tag should be created.

Comment: It seems that I am the only responder, and such fragmentation makes my job very difficult. See updated question.

Comment: @bato3: There are tons of legacy systems. Although unlikely, there can still be questions about the old version because someone has to bugfix/maintain, etc. with that old version. That's also a reason why old tags aren't removed.

Comment: About fragmentation: How version specific tags are used is mostly defined by the community. Some decided that their version specific tags should only be used in combination with the main tag, others think that either the main tag or the version tag should be used. I don't know what the consensus for kohana was.

Comment: Of course, there are tons of legacy systems, but 1) **such fragmentation makes it difficult to get answers**, beacause 2)  the community basically does not exist, and 3) I'm not talking about removing / disabling `kohana-2`, or `kohana-3.2`; So I think that these dead arrangements can be changed.